# How to override CSS style on extension button?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a browser extension.
On Stack Overflow, it creates a button on blocks with code.

I'm trying to apply my style to her. But nothing comes out. There is a link to the style in the code of the button element, you can see it in the attached picture. According to the advice from the Internet, I tried to specify the path in web_accessible_resources as `./contentscript.css`, it crashes with an error, cannot find the file.

Tell me where I went wrong?

[image: Promised picture]

Manifest:

```json
{
    "name": "__MSG_name__",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "default_locale": "en",
    "description": "__MSG_description__",
    "icons": {
        "32": "./icons/icon-32.png",
        "64": "./icons/icon-64.png",
        "128": "./icons/icon-128.png"
    },
 
    "content_scripts":[
        {
            "matches":["https://stackoverflow.com/*"],
            "run_at": "document_idle",
            "all_frames": false,
            "js": ["content-script.js"]
        }
    ], 
    "host_permissions": ["https://stackoverflow.com/*"],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        {
            "resources": ["contentscript.css"],
            "matches":["https://stackoverflow.com/*"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Javascript:

```js
const preEls = document.querySelectorAll('pre');
[...preEls].forEach(preEl =>{
 
    const root = document.createElement("div");
    root.style.position = "relative";
    const shadowRoot = root.attachShadow({mode : 'open'});
 
    const cssUrl = typeof browser === 'undefined'
        ? chrome.runtime.getURL("contentscript.css")
        : browser.runtime.getURL("contentscript.css");
 
    shadowRoot.innerHTML = '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' + cssUrl + '"></link>';
 
 
    const button = document.createElement("button");
    button.innerText = 'Copy';
    button.type = 'button';
    shadowRoot.prepend(button);
 
    preEl.prepend(root);
 
    const codeEl = preEl.querySelector('code');
 
    preEl.prepend(button);
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(codeEl.innerText)
        console.log('hey-hey')
    });
})
```

CSS:

```css
button{
    position: absolute !important;
    right: 12px !important;
    top: 6px !important;
    padding: 0.5em !important;
    background: #ffcc00 !important;
    color: black !important;
    border: none !important;
    border-radius: 3px !important;
    transition: background 0.15 ease-in-out !important;
    font-family: monospace !important;
}
 
button:hover{
    background: #e2b603 !important;
}
```

Comment: Try \`<style>@import "${cssUrl}"</style>\` instead. If it doesn't work reload you probably didn't reload the extension on `chrome://extensions` page after editing? Also, set a breakpoint inside the code and debug it in devtools.

Comment: @wOxxOm well, i defenetly reloaded the extension. Also can you explain, where exactly should I paste the code you sent? I never dealt with js or css before

Comment: Use it to replace everything after `innerHTML=`